# Hasse Diagram in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the following partial order on the set {a, b, c, d, e, f}:

{(a, a), (a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (a, e), (a, f),

(b, b), (b, c), (b, d), (b, e), (b, f),

(c, c),

(d, d), (d, f),

(e, e), (e, f),

(f, f)}

In the Hasse diagram for this partial order, how many edges go up out of node b?

Is there a way to find this out without drawing the hasse diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the elements that are above $b$ in the partial order but have nothing between them and $b$. There are four elements above $b$, namely, $c,d,e$, and $f$. However, $f$ is not directly above $b$: it’s above $d$, which is above $b$. Thus, in the Hasse diagram there’s no edge from $b$ up to $f$: there’s an edge from $b$ up to $d$ and one from $d$ up to $f$. (And $e$ also lies between $b$ and $f$.) However, there is nothing between $b$ and $c$, between $b$ and $d$, or between $b$ and $e$. For $d$, for instance, the only things below $d$, directly or otherwise, are $a$ and $b$, and $a$ is below $b$, so $b$ is directly below $d$ (and hence $d$ is directly above $b$).

Comment: So 4 edges would be correct?

Comment: @Varoag: yes, that’s right.

Comment: @Varoag: Oops! I wasn’t thinking: what I wrote isn’t right, because I counted non-direct linkages. Let me fix it for you.

Comment: @Varoag: I’m sorry about that, but it’s fixed now. (I’m apparently still not quite awake.)

Comment: Thanks! but now I'm confused. If we dont' count b to f and a, thers a connection between b and d. So there one edge?

Comment: @Varoag: There is one edge coming up from $a$ to $b$, and there are three edges going up from $b$ to $c,d$, and $e$; finally, there is an edge from $d$ up to $f$ and another from $e$ up to $f$. The relation itself tells you when some $x$ is below some $y$, but to see whether there’s an edge between them in the Hasse diagram, you have to check whether there’s an element between them in the order. In this example, for instance, $b$ is below $f$, but $e$ is between them, since $b$ is below $e$ which is below $f$, so there is no edge from $b$ to $f$.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks

Comment: @Varoag: You’re welcome.